# Visual Studio automated build: Makefile vs Project.sln

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

I want to automate the build process of my C++ application outside the Visual Studio IDE, via commandline.

Currently I use `devenv.com <solution-name>.sln /clean "Release|Win32" /project <project-name> /projectconfig "Release|Win32"` to build the solution.

There are several pre-build and post-build tasks that I configure inside the solution in the project config.

My question is: Is it recommended for an automated build process or I should use makefiles? If none of them, what approach should I use? (havind in mind that I need a reliable solution).

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend that you use qmake or cmake. I never have to worry about automation of my builds when I use qmake.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist thank you for your recommendation but for me seems like cmake is really useful when you have a multi-platform project and mine only targets windows.

Comment: True, but it also helps you get rid of the terribly horrible make process of Visual Studio. I never, ever, had to deal with that problem because of qmake and cmake.

Comment: I've read something about cmake not being compatible with VS2015. But aside from that, do you also use cmake to build when you are in the IDE?

Comment: I usually use qmake more than cmake. But, yes, I use both with Qt Creator.

Comment: @karuzo "cmake is really useful when you have a multi-platform project" -- I beg to differ. Have few dozen windows only production apps, all using a common library of cmake scripts (adding support for code generation, and various other handy features, and keeping everything consistent). CI system for all as well. IMHO CMakeLists are much easier to deal with than clicking through all the dialogs (or editing the MSVS solution and project files), as well as much easier to version.

Comment: @DanMašek I'm wondering about the development flow if I decide to use CMake. I couldn't find much information about using it with Visual Studio IDE. Can I replace the default build system for CMake during development? If so, is there any disadvantage of doing so?

Comment: @karuzo What exactly do you consider a buildsystem in this case? Basically CMake is a solution generator. Working locally, I run cmake, and then open the generated solution. When I compile, the solution automatically runs CMake to apply any modifications and regen/reload the solution and projects. Automation similarly runs CMake to create solution, and then `devenv` just like you do to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to build windows application with Makefile. You have to do a lot of work which is already done in msbuild. And you gain problems with visual studio integration. So I will definitely for building application from solution with msbuild.

Now for that additional tasks. Microsoft is not flexible in adding extra tasks. But if pre-build and post-build steps in a solution are sufficient for your needs, it is better to stick to one build system and use them. If you need something more powerful, it is worth using normal build system (makefiles are good and great, but now there are more easy to use alternatives, such as gradle, CMake and many more) and describe that extra steps in it, but still build application with msbuild.

Comment: I'm thinking about using standalone build tools and MSBuiild in a separate build server. Can I use the same MSBuild config in the build server and inside the Visual Studio IDE in my development enviromnent?

Comment: Msbuild uses the same .sln's, which Visual Studio uses.